# Order By not working in inner join query

Tags: sql

I am trying to sort my rows according to the `date` but its not working for me. Is there anything special need to be done to sort by `date`?

```
SELECT FI.*, User.* 
FROM FI INNER JOIN 
     User ON FI.U_ID = User.U_ID 
WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FI_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MON') = '$Month_Name' 
ORDER BY FI.FI_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using to_date(), I am guessing your fi_date column is not a date but a varchar. If that's the case, change your order by to 
ORDER BY to_date(fi.fi_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')

Comment: does it sort correctly if you just query FI with the same order by?

Comment: yes if i donot use inner join its working perfectly.

Comment: this is puzzling! I guess try listing out the columns instead of using *. Also I would try using parent query with order by - that of course is less efficient but something to at least try.

Comment: Ok, forgive me for doubting your first comment. But I still believe that FI_DATE is varchar2. Please describe FI table and confirm. I don't believe your to_date() would even work if FI_DATE was of type DATE.

Comment: no sorry that was my mistake. i am using pagination that why my order was not working. these all queries are now working :)